# What do the plus/minus numbers mean?

Tags: discussion, support

I was recently going through my questions when I clicked on one of them and accidentally clicked in the middle of the upvote and downvote buttons and this happened.

[image]

What does this mean? I have a fair idea what it is, but would still like an answer. Also, how did I get this? I could never do it before.

Answers are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably guessed, they are the upvote and downvote counts (two up, one down).

It is part of the [established user privileges](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) which are available at 750 reputation (which you just achieved) on beta sites, or 1,000 reputation on graduated sites.